# inline if statement with php

Tags: php, magento

im trying to obtain value true of false depending on a certain condition

```
<script>
    require(['swiper', 'jquery'], function(Swiper, $){
        var swiper_selector = '.items-swiper-skrey-slider-tab<?=$_uniqid;?>';
        var swiper = new Swiper($(swiper_selector),{
            slidesPerView: <?= $block->isCountdownActive()?4:5?>,
            spaceBetween: 20,
            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 0
                },
                640: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                spaceBetween: 0
                },
                767: {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 0
                },
                1000: {
                slidesPerView: <?= $block->isCountdownActive()?4:5?>,
                spaceBetween: 0
                }
            },
            preloadImages: true,
            updateOnImagesReady: true,
            mousewheel: false,
               // ---- gestures (permite arrastar o slider usando o rato)----
            simulateTouch: <?= ($block->getData('is_gestures') == "1") ?true:false?>,
```

that simulateTouch: can have a value of true or false and i want to be true if my getData value is 1 or false if the value is 0.

Its working when the value is 1 and it changes what i want. But the other things that have value 0 get bugged because this inline statement doesnt work like that.
I want something like if $block->getData('is_gestures') == "1" simulateTouch: true
if $block->getData('is_gestures') == "0" simulateTouch: false.
Im working with magento and php and this getData come from a widget parameter name that has a Yes or No select. Basiccly i want to change the swiper configuration based on that yes or no answer.

Comment: The actual problem is that `<?=` is basically the same as an `echo` - and `true` output via echo, gets you `1` as result, whereas with `false` it only gets you an _empty string_. Which means the JS code you generate, will be `simulateTouch: ,`, and since there is no actual value before the comma, that’s a syntax error. You should be using _text literals_ here, not the actual boolean PHP types. `… ? 'true':'false'`

Comment: @CBroe yes that was the problem. Its working now . Thank you very much